# I have combined my backend and angular on single port , but doing so my apis are not working anymore

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I have a frontend and backend configured to run on a single server, but by doing so my backend apis are not functioning properly. Means the apis are getting called by my frontend but not getting the result back from the api.

//I have tried various ways to make the apis work but cant get the response from the api.

//package.json file start script

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "npm run build & concurrently --kill-others \"npm run serve-api\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "serve": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "ng build --output-path=public",
    "serve-api": "node app.js",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  }
```

//node api
// Admin login

```
router.post("/api/loginAdmin", (req, res) => {
  console.log("login admin works");
  admin.findOne({ email: req.body.email }).then(user => {
    console.log(req.body.email);
    console.log(user);
    if (!user) res.send({ success: 0, msg: "Admin is not registered with us" });
    const isPasswordValid = bcrypt.compareSync(
      req.body.password,
      user.password
    );
    if (!isPasswordValid) {
      res.send({ success: 0, data: "password do not match" });
    }
    const token = jwt.sign({ id: user._id }, config.secret, {
      expiresIn: config.jwt_expiry
    });
    const userObject = user.toObject();
    delete userObject.password;
    console.log(token, userObject);
    res.send({ success: 1, token: token, user: userObject, data: true });
  });
  console.log("not working");
});
```

//app.js file which is configured to run while front end starts.(only needed code)
// APi route

```
const adminTask = require("./xcifi nodeapi's - 1/api/adminTask");
app.use("/", adminTask);
// Apis for posts
const post = require("./xcifi nodeapi's - 1/api/post");
app.use("/", post);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "public"));
app.get("*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "public/index.html"));
});

//app config file
export const appConfig = {
  apiUrl: "http://localhost:3000/api"
  // apiUrl: "https://afternoon-beyond-81594.herokuapp.com"
};
```

//simple angular service where api is getting called
// isloggedin method

```
isLoggedIn(data) {
    this.http
      .post<any>(appConfig.apiUrl + "/loginAdmin", data)
      .pipe(
        map(data => {
          console.log(data);
          if (data.data) {
            localStorage.setItem("isLoggedIn", data.data);
            localStorage.setItem("token", data.token);

            localStorage.setItem("userName", data.user.name);
            localStorage.setItem("userEmail", data.user.email);

            localStorage.setItem("userAdminStatus", data.user.isSuperAdmin);

            console.log(
              localStorage.getItem("isLoggedIn"),
              localStorage.getItem("userEmail")
            );
          }
          return data;
        })
      )
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data;
        console.log(this.data);
      });
  }
```

//i Just want my api to return the data.

Comment: Are you getting some sort of error? You need to be more specific, what '*doesn't work*'?

Comment: @NicholasK The api works....means the first console.log and the last console.log gives the output....but the middle part which us admin.findone doesnt work....it doesnt return any data at all....and it isnt showing any error

Comment: why couldnt you run them on two different ports?

Comment: @O.MeeKoh I want to deploy the app on a single server ..... dont want to deploy it on 2 different servers

Comment: trying to avoid CORS?

Comment: @O.MeeKoh Naah....thats not the issue....i already implemented CORS policy

Comment: but you wont need CORS policy.

Comment: Yep , but i did it anyways cz prior frontend and backend were on different ports ..... just recently combined it to run on single port

Comment: i understand. I was hoping I could be of more help but i see you are using node and express, and for some reason i thought you were on asp.net core.

Comment: Haha....its ok man